# How to automatically select return/co_return in C++

Tags: c++, c++-coroutine

I'm writing my own testing framework and I want it to be able to return/co_return a value if a test failed with a uniform syntex. However I can't find a way to make a macro that returns regardless if it's in a coroutine or in a function.The compiler seems to not have any flags that tells a macro if it's in a coroutine. Is there a solution?

For example:

```
// RETURN is the magic macro that automatically
// decides if it should `return` or `co_return`

int foo()
{
    RETURN(5);
    // expands to `return 5;
}

cppcoro::task<int> bar()
{
    RETURN(5);
    // expands to `co_return 5;
}
```

Comment: This cannot be done in general. If `task<int>` were constructible from `int` (e.g., to represent an already-completed a task), then both `return 5;` and `co_return 5;` would be legal, and they have different meanings. You cannot check from within the function whether it is a coroutine, because whether it is a coroutine depends on what's inside the function - it's a catch-22!